# Python, class attribute error

Tags: python, class, object, attributes

I have a set of code  that looks like this:

```
class DataFilter:

    def __init__(self, csvData):
        # converts csv string data to float lists, if possible
        data = []
        for line in csvData:
            try:
                line = line.split(',')
            except:
                print(line)
                return

            for i in range( len(line) ):
                try:
                    line[i] = float(line[i])
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            data.append(line)
        self.data = data

    def find_depth_index(self, depth):
        for index, line in enumerate( self.data ):
            if line[1] > depth:
                return index

    def remove_above_depth(self, depth):
        index = self.find_depth_index( depth )
        return self.data[ index: ]

    def remove_beyond_depth(self, depth):
        index = self.find_depth_index(depth)
        return self.data[ :index ]

data = DataFilter(data).remove_above_depth(SURF_CASING_DEPTH)
print('-----------------------')
data = DataFilter(data).remove_beyond_depth(VERTICAL_SEC_DEPTH)
```

Then it give me an error:

```
  File "C:/Users/Eric Soobin Kim/PycharmProjects/untitled/RAPID_use_filtered_data.py", line 35, in remove_beyond_depth
    def remove_beyond_depth(self, depth):
  File "C:/Users/Eric Soobin Kim/PycharmProjects/untitled/RAPID_use_filtered_data.py", line 26, in find_depth_index
    def find_depth_index(self, depth):
AttributeError: 'DataFilter' object has no attribute 'data'
```

The thing that I don't understand is that, it ran without a problem for the line:

```
data = DataFilter(data).remove_above_depth(SURF_CASING_DEPTH)
```

but its not working for,

```
data = DataFilter(data).remove_beyond_depth(VERTICAL_SEC_DEPTH)
```

I think my first filtering somehow alters elements in `__ini__()`, but i don't know what's going on. Why is this happening, and how can i fix it?

Comment: Looks like you are hitting the `return` in the `except` block and `self.data` will never be set.

Comment: @KlausD. I edited my code. I see what you are saying. But in my code, there was no exception raised, so return was not the source of error here. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Eric Kim Can you post the whole code?  What values does data have initially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've reassigned **data** to be equal to something other than what you want.

```
data = DataFilter(data).remove_above_depth(SURF_CASING_DEPTH)
```

This means that now you've lost the pointer to data that you once had.   Might I suggest making a copy like

```
new_data = DataFilter(data).remove_above_depth(SURF_CASING_DEPTH)
new_data2 = DataFilter(data).remove_beyond_depth(VERTICAL_SEC_DEPTH)
```

This way you still have the reference to the old `data` variable

Comment: This is the correct answer, but it's _severely_ lacking in explanation. How does changing the value of a variable prevent an instance attribute from being created?

Comment: @Aran-Fey How's that?

Comment: Im not sure if this is what I want, because I am supposed to apply two filters to my data. So, first I filter the data points that doesn't fit my first filter, and then using the filtered data, I apply my second filter.

Comment: I don't see a difference. There's no explanation why the `data` attribute isn't being created. In fact I'm starting to wonder if you misunderstood the question.

Comment: @frank No, there was no exception raised in my code. I deleted return in my __init__ function, and it ran fine without raising exception.

Comment: Sorry, there was something wrong with me code. i will accept your answer

Comment: @EricKim As long as you solved the problem and you understand what was wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Object has no attribute data because you didnt give it the attribute. 
atributes are defined by making writing: 
    self.object = []
instead of:
    object = []

Comment: _"you didnt give it the attribute"_ Yes they did: `self.data = data`.